# How to get KeePass 2.X running on MAC OS X

Tags: .net, macos, mono, keepass

I just installed the latest version of `Mono` and `XQuartz`. I downloaded `Keepass-2.29` portable edition. And when I try to run it, I get the following exceptions :

> $ mono KeePass.exe
> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
> was thrown by the type initializer for
> System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
> type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
> type initializer for System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
> type initializer for System.Drawing.KnownColors --->
> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
> type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus --->
> System.DllNotFoundException:
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/libgdiplus.dylib
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup
> (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
> at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Drawing.Color.get_Black () [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeWin32Classic..cctor () [0x00000] in
> :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeVisualStyles..ctor () [0x00000] in
> :0    at System.Windows.Forms.ThemeEngine..cctor ()
> [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack
> trace ---   at
> System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.get_MenuAccessKeysUnderlined ()
> [0x00000] in :0    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
> System.Windows.Forms.Control:.ctor ()   at
> System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext..cctor ()
> [0x00000] in :0    --- End of inner exception stack
> trace ---   at System.Windows.Forms.Control..ctor () [0x00000] in
> :0    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl..ctor () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl..ctor ()
> [0x00000] in :0    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Form..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
> at KeePass.Forms.MainForm..ctor () [0x00000] in :0
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) KeePass.Forms.MainForm:.ctor
> ()   at KeePass.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
> :0
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception
> was thrown by the type initializer for System.Drawing.GDIPlus --->
> System.DllNotFoundException:
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/libgdiplus.dylib
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup
> (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
> at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Drawing.KnownColors..cctor () [0x00000] in :0

Need some more guidance here on what is this indicating and how to proceed to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

KeePass 2.X portable edition is unstable in Mac. In certain cases, read operation works but cannot add or update existing keePass databases.

Alternative [KeePass 2.x for Mac OS X](http://keepass.info/download/p_macosx/index.html) - is also unstable. It remains in version 2.23 while keePass is now 2.29. With latest Mono and XQuartz, this keePass package throws lot of exception.

[Best working version is keePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/). Based on my personal usage, this release looks far better and stable than other existing KeePass packages for Mac.

Comment: KeePassX is now final (see https://www.keepassx.org/news/2015/12/533). And it be installed with homebrew cask : "brew cask install keepassx"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Mono installation is incomplete. Did you install the MRE or the MDK?

Did you install via the pkg from http://mono-project.com or via brew?

If you installed the MRE or installed via brew, try installing the MDK from the mono website. Otherwise just try re-installing.

Comment: I installed and reinstalled the MDK, but the error persists.

Comment: does the .dylib file exist?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that. I don't know what file you are referring to.

Comment: The DLL that is failing to load: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.12.1/lib/libgdiplus.dylib

Answer (score 0):

If not already done, consider installing [Homebrew package manager for Mac OS](https://brew.sh/) by executing the following in the Terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

And then using it to install the [KeepassXC](https://keepassxc.org/download/#):

```
brew install --cask keepassxc
```